# After publishing application error occurs in finding path to database and xml files

Tags: c#

I have OS XP Russian version, after installing programm shows errors "path in russian can not be read" - explaining in my way. Does anybody have any idea? Thanks

```
    public string getDBpath() {
                string path1 = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath;
                string path2 = "safer.sdf";
                string path3 = Path.Combine(path1, path2);
                return path3;

            }

            public string getXmlPath() {
                string path1 = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath;
                string path2 =  @"data/fp.xml";
                string path3 = Path.Combine(path1, path2);
                return path3;
            }

            public string getXmlPathTxt() {
                string path1 = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath;
                string path2 = @"data/xml_data.txt";
                string path3 = Path.Combine(path1, path2);
                return path3;
            }
```

Comment: What do these methods return, and what do you expect them to return? Can you somehow log the return value from these methods?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would solve the problem but you could try changing the `System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath` to `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`, and see if that fixes it.

```
public string getDBpath() {
            string path1 = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
            string path2 = "safer.sdf";
            string path3 = Path.Combine(path1, path2);
            return path3;

        }

        public string getXmlPath() {
            string path1 = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
            string path2 =  @"data/fp.xml";
            string path3 = Path.Combine(path1, path2);
            return path3;
        }

        public string getXmlPathTxt() {
            string path1 = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
            string path2 = @"data/xml_data.txt";
            string path3 = Path.Combine(path1, path2);
            return path3;
        }
```

Comment: no problem, I was wondering if it had to do with maybe something being in the GAC on deployment and so the GetExecutingAssembly.Location would give you the path to where the dll/exe is physically located on the system.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `Thread.GetDomain().BaseDirectory` instead of `System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath`.

If this is not working I would advice you to attach to the deployed version of your application. Therefor you can easily add `Debugger.Launch();` right befor your pathes are created.